# rackup undefined local variable or method `env' for Rulers::Application:Class (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I just start reading "Rebuilding Rails" by Noah Gibbs. I'm stuck at page17 where def call(env) is declared.

However, when I run rackup, I came across this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `env' for Rulers::Application:Class (NameError)
```

How can I define 'env' ?

Comment: here is a free version of the book. http://rebuilding-rails.com/RebuildingRailsFree.pdf

Comment: Show your exact code

Comment: Mistake should be in `rulers/lib/rulers.rb`.

Comment: this is my rulers.rb

require "rulers/version"

module Rulers
 class Application
    def call(env)
      [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'},
        ["Hello from Ruby on Rulers!" + env.inspect]]
    end
 end
end

Comment: Have you built the rulers gem and installed it properly?

Comment: For future viewers: the free version above is just the first few chapters. (I'm the author)

Comment: That's a bit of an odd error message for that part of the book. You've added the "+ env.inspect", which is presumably where that error came from. But env should be defined there -- it should be the param. Did it work before you added the "+ env.inspect" to the end?

Comment: Also: can you post the call stack? (edit: or check your code into a repo and post a link?)

Comment: no. it didn't work. I added env.inspect to see what's wrong. But it never reach that line of the code.

Comment: gem was built and installed.

Comment: here is my repo for the ruler gem https://github.com/hszeto/rulers

Comment: Could you push to that repo? It has no code in lib/rulers.rb

Comment: sorry. please reload.

Comment: here is the repo for the app. https://github.com/hszeto/best_quotes

Comment: The error mentions `env` as a class method. Please post more context and code. The repo is still mostly empty.

Comment: Just a reminder that the question itself should contains everything needed to answer it--reference to an off-site repo may be useful to those generous persons who want to help, but the question itself still needs improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got some kind of weird Unicode characters in your lib/rulers.rb. Reformat with normal spaces and/or tabs and it'll work fine. I reproduced the same bug locally from your repo (after "git rm rulers-0.1.0.gem" in your Rulers directory), fixed the spaces and it works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks Noah Gibbs! how do you see those unicode? I'm using Sublime Text.

Comment: I found them in emacs -- vi also responds oddly to them.